# Can we play “A Way Out” co-op with PC and PS4

Tags: a-way-out

I've a pc and I was wondering that can i play this game with my friend who has a ps4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, A Way Out does not support cross play. As is mentioned [here](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Game-Information/A-WAY-OUT-CROSS-PLAY/td-p/6666159)